# GNURadio Companion and OFDM TX and RX in single Graph

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am following this [github](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/a94c4f228750213c20ea51a3e9a31283942052f1/gr-digital/examples/ofdm/tx_ofdm.grc) example for understanding [OFDM](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/tree/main/gr-digital/examples/ofdm) on gnuradio-companion, I am able to execute `ofdm_tx`  individually (64 and 512 FFT point) without any issues,  but when I connect these two  in single graph, I am able to get spectrum from `ofdm_tx` (no output from `ofdm_rx` or getting straight line).

My question here, each time I close my output spectrum, my tool get hanged and in background (inside gnu-companion) I observe the following message tarin (attached, printscreen). Similar thing also observed when I run ofdm_rx individually.

Error message in Console :

packet_headerparser_b :info: Detected an invalid packet at item 1448.
header_payload_demux :info :parser returned #f

Please guide me in this regard,

[image: OFDM TX RX Graph]

Comment: Please [edit] to add a transcription of your first image of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 0):

by selecting "**NO**" for vector source "**Repeat**" variable , issue sorted out (no hang), but not able to see spectrum anymore.